In Angular, the child component does not understand the CSS of the parent component
In Angular 17, I have a div with the class wrapper-my
.wrapper-my {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: stretch
  width: 100%
}

.my-class {
  width: inherit;
}

// parent component
<div class="wrapper-my">
    <input type="text" class="my-class">
    <app-input-my></app-input-my>
</div>

And in app-input-my I have an input.
.my-class2 {
  width: inherit
}
<input type="text" class="my-class2">

The input that is not in a component fills the entire space.
However, the input that is in app-input-my does not fill the entire space
Even after doing this, it still doesn't work.
<app-input-my class="my-class"></app-input-my>

How do I make my component work correctly according to the parent tag?

We need to take not of two things,

Components when created do not have a height property, so for safety I applied display: block; width:100% so that the parent dimensions are inherited!

Input does not react to width: inherit instead go for width:100% which will inherit the parent width!


INPUT MY
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-my',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<input type="text" class="my-class2">`,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .my-class2 {
        width: inherit;
      }
  `,
  ],
})
export class InputMyComponent {}

MAIN
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { InputMyComponent } from './app/input-my/input-my.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [InputMyComponent],
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper-my">
      <input type="text" class="my-class">
      <app-input-my></app-input-my>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    :host {
      width:100px;
      display: block;
    }
    .wrapper-my {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
      align-self: stretch;
    }

    .my-class {
      width: 100%;
    }
  `,
  ],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Angular shims the css classes to emulate view encapsulation (a bit like with ShadowDom).
For your parent style to work on your child component you have to either :

Make you style global
use ViewEncapsulation.None on the parent.

 
@Component({
  ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class WrapperParentComponent { }


It didn't work, I tried with ::ng-deep and ViewEncapsulation.None

What can work is ::ng-deep
docs
It is "deprecated" for years.
from the docs:

The following example targets all  elements, from the host element down through this component to all of its child elements in the DOM.

:host ::ng-deep h3 {
  font-style: italic;
}

